# I want to use two different custom cells from nib in a single table view. The two prototype cells have different heights

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a situation where I have to use two different prototype cells for a single tableView. These two prototype cells have different heights. When I am trying to run the application  I am not getting different heights of the cell. Instead, I am getting overlapping cells. The cells are overlapped on each other at index 2.

I have made two xib for the cells and registered the two cells in tableview. 
[Screenshot of what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfOit.png)

```
extension Redeem: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0{

            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedeemCell1", for: indexPath) as! RedeemCell1
            return cell1
        } else if indexPath.row == 1{
             let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedeemCell1", for: indexPath) as! RedeemCell1

            return cell1

        } else if indexPath.row == 2{
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedeemCell2", for: indexPath)  as! RedeemCell2

            return cell2
        } else if indexPath.row == 3{
             let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedeemCell1", for: indexPath) as! RedeemCell1

            return cell1
        } else {
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedeemCell1", for: indexPath) as! RedeemCell1

            return cell1
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
}
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot from Debug View Hierarchy?

Comment: I don't know how to debug view hierarchy. Can you please help.?

Comment: follow https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2

you should tap on that red cornered button

Comment: we need to understand what a height has cells and its content views

Comment: I am not able to attach a screenshot here. How should I send the screenshot.

Comment: you can add it to screenshot service, like imgur.com or prnt.sc, and attach the link. also, you can edit you main post, and attach link to it.

Comment: This is the screenshot url:
https://imgur.com/RHkAK4r

Comment: can you rotate it and zoom it, for understanding TableViewCell frame and its contentView frame?

Comment: okay . Let me try.

Comment: https://imgur.com/LY7lWZl

Comment: yep, I was right, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603204/7707189
so, you should fix layout in your custom cells

Comment: I think it is 120, your estimatedRowHeight. AutomaticRowDimension doesn't work, because you custom cells has incorrect constraints.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your help. It means a lot to me. Got to learn many things from you. thanks!

Comment: Can you please point me towards some useful guide to auto layouting.?

Comment: you can get it on my post below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the cells are not layouted correctly.

> To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints
>   and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content
>   view’s top edge and its bottom edge.

If you use XIBs in cells, you can change simulated size in cell, and see what's happened. The cell should be without broken constraints.

Comment: I don't get. How to fix it. I am a new developer. Your support is appreciated .

Comment: please follow this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Comment: so, you should add constrain to 4 edges (top, bottom, left, right or width, height, left, right etc) to all you subviews.

Comment: did you fix this issue? if you was, you can mark my answer as resolved. otherwise, you can add additional information, so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Davydov for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either implement `heightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
   if indexPath.row == 0 {
       return 200
    }
    else if {} // and so on 
}
```

or use dynamic height table cells

Comment: I am using these two properties:
redeemTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
redeemTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

Comment: then it's dynamic , so you need to properly set constraints from top to bottom of the cell . make sure you don't have a break in between

Comment: Okay. Let me check the constraints.